# Celery Flower - how can i load previous catched tasks?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, flower

I started to use celery flower for tasks monitoring and it is working like a charm. I have one concern though, how can i "reload" info about monitored tasks after flower restart ?
I use redis as a broker, and i need to have option to check on tasks even in case of unexpected restart of service (or server).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found i out. 
It is the matter of setting the persistant flag in command running celery flower.

Comment: could you share with me what flag did you add to the command?

Comment: Kapucko not sure after all this time, but it seems it was this: http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#persistent

Comment: yeah, already tried but didn't work for me. I'm using Rabbitmq as a broker... that may be the issue. Thanks.