# celery flower does not show previously run tasks after restart

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, flower

I am using celery with django and using flower to inspect tasks. I am using rabbitmq as broker. It all works fine but after I restart flower, the previously listed states of task is lost and I see 0 entries in flower.

I am running flower with persistent mode too.

> python -m celery -A curatepro -l debug flower --persistent
>   --db=/var/lib/flower/flowerdb

There is a similar question asked on this SO post:

[Celery Flower - how can i load previous catched tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553659/celery-flower-how-can-i-load-previous-catched-tasks)

and as it suggests using --persistent flag and I am using the same but still it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the variable as `--persistent=True` for this to work.